# How to get the VideoID or VideoUrl from VideoItem in Forms App?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to get the video ID or Url from a VideoItem in FormsApp.

I can see the `setVideoUrl()` method, but I do not find a getter method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

There is no functionality built into the FormsApp for this. However, if you're willing to dabble in Youtube Data API (This needs to be enabled). Then you might be able to use some of the search functions in there to return the ID. I was messing around with it, and it seems to work. Not sure what your forms look like though, so i can't say if it  will work for you or not.

Comment: What would you use as search parameter?